# A better way to write this jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance

How could I re-write this code to be more DRY?
I have simply adapted this and expanded it, but obviously there would be abetter way to write this. Just not sure how?

```
incomeSum();
expenseSum();
debtSum();
savingsSum();
billsSum();

function incomeSum() {
    var sum=0;
    //iterate through each input and add to sum
    $('#income .amount').each(function() {     
            sum += parseInt($(this).text());                     
    }); 
    //change value of total
    $('#income .total').html('$'+sum);
}
function expenseSum() {
    var sum=0;
    //iterate through each input and add to sum
    $('#expense .amount').each(function() {     
            sum += parseInt($(this).text());                     
    }); 
    //change value of total
    $('#expense .total').html('$'+sum);
} 

etc etc ....
```

Comment: I don't know but it seems a little bit off to ask so for rewriting your jQuery twice. Maybe google stuff before and try out stuff

Answer (score 2):

One way is to supply the selectors as arguments to the function:

```
function sum(inputSelector, outputSelector) {
    var sum=0;
    //iterate through each input and add to sum
    $(inputSelector).each(function() {     
            sum += parseInt($(this).text());                     
    }); 
    //change value of total
    $(ouputSelector).html('$'+sum);
}
```

**Usage**

```
sum("#expense .amount", "#expense .total");
```

Another way is to pass the jQuery objects as arguments:

```
function sum($inputs, $output) {
    var sum=0;
    //iterate through each input and add to sum
    $inputs.each(function() {     
            sum += parseInt($(this).text());                     
    }); 
    //change value of total
    $output.html('$'+sum);
}
```

**Usage**

```
sum($('#expense .amount'), $('#expense .total'));
```

Comment: +1 for giving a range of options (tho i prefer the 2nd personally)!1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function awesomeSum(id) {
    var sum=0;
    $(id).find('.amount').each(function() {     
            sum += parseInt($(this).text());                     
    }); 
    //change value of total
    $(id).find('.total').html('$'+sum);
}
```

And then:

```
$.each(['#income', '#expense', '#debt', '#bills'], function(){

  awesomeSum(this);

});
```